# ORDER BY MONTH(1) after GROUP_CONCAT as names?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I don't use `GROUP_CONCAT()` then there is no difficulty to the group and order the rows according to date-month-year

Following code:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(orders.date_time,'%d %m %Y') AS date,
    SUM(orders.net_amount) AS total_sales,
    COUNT(FROM_UNIXTIME(orders.date_time,'%D %b %Y')) AS total_orders
FROM orders 
JOIN users ON orders.user_id = users.id
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(orders.date_time,'%d %m %Y') != DATE_FORMAT(users.reg_date_time, '%d %m %Y')
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY Month(1)
```

O/P:

```
21 12 2019  1092    1   pinky
04 01 2020  1050    1   harshit
30 12 2019  21  1   robin
05 01 2020  987 2   chetan
31 12 2019  1239    2   rahul
30 11 2019  157.5   1   rahul
01 01 2020  651 1   rahul
15 12 2019  1575    1   isha
03 01 2020  598.5   1   manvi
```

SEE the names are not concating

But as soon as I add this line:

`GROUP_CONCAT(users.firstname SEPARATOR '-')) AS names`

like this:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(orders.date_time,'%d %m %Y') AS date,
    SUM(orders.net_amount) AS total_sales,
    GROUP_CONCAT(users.firstname SEPARATOR '-') AS names,
    COUNT(FROM_UNIXTIME(orders.date_time,'%D %b %Y')) AS total_orders
FROM orders 
JOIN users ON orders.user_id = users.id
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(orders.date_time,'%d %m %Y') != DATE_FORMAT(users.reg_date_time, '%d %m %Y')
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY Month(1)
```

O/P:

```
01 01 2020  651 1   rahul
03 01 2020  598.5   1   manvi
04 01 2020  1050    1   harshit
05 01 2020  987 2   chetan-saurabh
15 12 2019  1575    1   isha
21 12 2019  1092    1   pinky
30 11 2019  157.5   1   rahul
30 12 2019  21  1   robin
31 12 2019  1239    2   rahul-manvi
```

then the order changed by day-order(without proper month and year order) but the grouping is correct.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's the point of calling `CONCAT()` with just one argument? What are you concatenating?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but `COUNT(FROM_UNIXTIME(orders.date_time,'%D %b %Y'))` should just be `COUNT(*)`. Giving an argument to `COUNT()` is only necessary if it could be null and you don't want to count the null values, or you're doing `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`

Comment: You're not ordering by month and year, you're just ordering by month. So January 2019 and January 2020 will be ordered together.

Comment: I am trying to concat users first name from users table on a date, like if two users placed orderd on same day, so  I want to add those two rows on that date.

Comment: That's what `GROUP_CONCAT()` does. `CONCAT()` is for concatenating something else to the result of that.

Comment: I think the problem is `Month(1)`. That should be `Month(date)`

Comment: Month(date) is still not working AND  please check the query again I mistakenly added the concat() function

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data showing the incorrect results?

Comment: I have added the output now, please check

Comment: `MONTH()` expects the argument to be a `DATETIME` or a string that can be parsed as a datetime. `01 01 2020` is not in a parsable format.

Comment: MySQL expects dates to be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY MONTH(orders.date_time)`. The problem is that your `date` column is not formatted as a valid MySQL date, so it's not extracting the month correctly.